# Using a classifier to make a confusion matrix, python

Tags: python-2.7, matrix, confusion-matrix

So i've been tasked with making a leave one out classifier and then using said classifier to make a confusion matrix, my classifier works but I was wondering how you would use it to then make a confusion matrix.
The leave one out classifier returns:

```
correct = index==data[test_index,0]
return correct
```

which is a boolean, how can this be used to make a confusion matrix

Comment: would you mind adding more of your code for context?